# Modificar Script y ruta de trabajo

Tags: r, script

Estoy aprendiendo a importar bases de datos con `read_csv` y `read_delim` y a compartir proyectos de r.

Por ello, quisiera saber ¿cómo puedo modificar mi ruta de trabajo de tal manera que cuando comparta mis proyectos, como archivos comprimidos, las personas que los abran puedan correr los comandos desde la carpeta comprimida?

Comment: es una carpeta comprimida (.rar o .zip) o una carpeta compartida (en un servidor o algo similar)?

Comment: Opción numero 1 es crear un paquete, es complejo pero si duda lo mejor. La opción 2 si usas Rstudio es crear un proyecto y distribuir la carpeta del mismo. De cualquier de las dos formas, si te funciona a tí, debería funcionarle a cualquier otro usuario

Comment: Es una carpeta comprimida(.rar)

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero de todo sería, que en el caso de que estés editando tu script desde algún IDE no copiaras y pegaras tu script en la consola sino que abrieras tus script como si fueran un proyecto todos a la vez.

Una vez hecho eso, tendrías que pasarle a read_csv la ruta de donde tienes tu fichero como una ruta relativa. Por ejemplo, tu estructura de carpetas es así

- fichero1.R
- fichero2.R
- datos -> dato.csv

En ese caso tu función de read_csv lanzado desde tu fichero fichero1.R sería así

```
datos <- read_csv("datos/dato.csv")
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda